# How to make a div follow the mouse's pointer only when hovering a box?

Tags: javascript

I am a total beginner, so can somebody please help me with this. When you hover over one of these boxes, I want `div class="title"` to follow the cursor inside of that box. Vanilla js solution please. [Look at the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5evEj.png). And here is the code so far:

```
const thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".container .thumb");
const title = document.querySelector(".thumb .title")

function divMoves() {
    title.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        let x = e.offsetX + "px";
        let y = e.offsetY + "px";
        title.style.top = x;
        title.style.left = y;
    })
};

thumbs.forEach(thumb => {
    thumb.addEventListener("mouseover", divMoves);
    thumb.addEventListener("mouseleave");
});
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow.  We are happy to help out here but we are not minions summoned from the darkest basement dungeons to write code for no money.  Please share what you have attempted to do so we can take a look and guide you.

Comment: Have you put any efforts Dear @Jan Kucic?

Comment: Here it is. My understanding is really bad right now of course, cuz I am a beginner. So a little bit of help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `mousemove` event on title but instead on the element(s) you want your title to be hovered on. You can use `pageX` and `pageY` properties to get the coordinates of the pointer on the document and apply those values to `left` and `top` properties of your `title` element

```
const thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const title = document.querySelectorAll(".title")
const onMouseMove = (e, i) => {

  title[i].style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  title[i].style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

thumbs.forEach((thumb, i) => {
    thumb.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => onMouseMove(e, i));
});
```

See sample [here](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/wvWxedp?editors=1010)

Comment: One more thing. Now, when I hover the other boxes, the title from the first box moves...In my example, I have four boxes and one title in each box, I want to move the title in the box that I hovered. How can I achieve that? And thank you very much for the help!

Comment: In that case, you should get the index from `forEach` loop and pass to the `onMouseMove` function and use it with `title`, I've updated the code for it.